# Dynamically add div elements with unique ID associated using angular

Tags: angular, typescript3.0

I want to to dynamically add div element with custom ID each time the button is clicked.

```
<div class="container">
    <div *ngFor="let div of divs" id="{{selectedPeerSocketID}}">Newly div created</div>
  </div>
```

it sets same id to each divs created

```
<button (click) = "onClick()">Add Div</button>
<div class="container">
    <div *ngFor="let div of divs" id="{{selectedPeerSocketID}}">Newly div created</div>
  </div>
```

----TypeScript----

```
selectedPeerSocketID: // this gets value from another feature
divs: number[] = [];
onClick(){
  this.divs.push(this.divs.length);
}
```

I expect div elements creation with custom id.

Comment: I'm running on Angular 8 & typescript 3

Comment: The question is; HOW does selectedPeerSocketID gets its value and how does it get updated in the onClick?

Comment: This is basically for chatting functionality. i have a table with list of sockets having unique IDs. when i click table row button, i will get respective table row ID. now i want to create a div with this table row ID.

Comment: So how do you set that value? Can you give some code?

Comment: <table>
<!-- clientSocketID Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="clientSocketID">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="columnSocketIDHead"> SocketID </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="columnSocketIDData"> {{element.clientSocketID}} </td>
      </ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="onClick(row)"></tr>
</table>

.ts 
onClick(tr) {
    this.selectedPeerSocketID = tr.clientSocketID;
}

Comment: whenever a new socket connects to the browser, server generates socketID & through service socketID gets injected to the table row.
There may be n number of sockets, each will have unique socketID. so my requirement is, whenever end user clicks on any socket in the table, a new div should be created with the div id: socketID clicked.
i know it's too much of explanation, hope you got this.

Comment: your divs, can be an array of string, so onClick(tr){this.divs.push(ts.clientSockedID)} and use [id]="div"

Comment: @Eliseo, it will push clientSockedID to divs[ ] and what does [id] ="div" do?

Comment: it's the same [id]="div" than id="{{div}}", where "div" is the variable of your loop *ngFor="let **div** of divs"

Comment: so [id]="div" will update only that respective div (not any previous divs). is that what you mean?

Comment: @Eliseo, thanks mate. I just tried your solution. it worked for me.